# Python dict tuple out of range

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
f = open('File4Gym.dat')
try:
    db = lite.connect('/var/www/members.db')
    fieldnames = ('Shop', 'PUC Code Num', 'Name', 'Date/ Reason', 'Amount', 'T', 'PUC Code', 'Status', 'Date')
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    for row in reader:
            for fieldnames in row.items():
            #print row
                    if fieldnames[5] <> '0.00' or '14.95' or '16.95':
                            print "Committing INSERT"
                            c = db.execute("""INSERT "debit" = '%s' FROM "members" WHERE "puccode" = '%s'""" % (fieldnames[5], fieldnames[7],))
```

Which returns the error:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python cronjob3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cronjob3.py", line 13, in <module>
if fieldnames[5] <> '0.00' or '14.95' or '16.95':
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

How would I go about referring to the individual fields in the csv.DictReader and inserting values other than the ones in the "if" statement into the SQL table?

Sample file (as requested):

```
"Shop Name",PUCLxxx,"Customer 1","09/09/2014",0.00,T,"PUCLxxx","Closed Account ",20140909
"Shop Name",PUCLyyy,"Customer 2","09/09/2014",0.00,T,"PUCLyyy","Closed Account ",20140909
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Note for me: I've got to do the reverse order of that too, if the value is inserted as a debit other than the amounts listed, then returns to those amounts, I need to update accordingly, but I'll try to work on it once I get this question sorted...

Comment: Can you add a minimal sample file to your question that exhibits the problem? (I'm assuming this will contain, at most, two lines).

Comment: where did you see `<>` being used?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham He's preparing for PEP 401: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0401/

Comment: @matsjoyce, some exciting things to look forward to!

Comment: "Not that PSU, the other PSU..." - far too many PSUs, I'm afraid... I'm usually confined to the hardware domain... *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

Which `fieldnames` are you trying to access? You define it as `('Shop', 'PUC...` but then use `for fieldnames in row:`. I imagine one of them needs to be renamed.

The new `fieldnames` must be shorter than 6 elements. Try printing it out in the loop to see what is returned.

Edit: I think I've found the issue.

Where you have `for fieldnames in row.items():` `fieldnames` iterates over the key/value pairs in the dictionary `row`. Each pair is a 2-tuple so 5 is out of range.

I think replacing your `for` loop with the following should do what you're trying to achieve

```
for row in reader:
    if row['Amount'] <> '0.00' or '14.95' or '16.95':  #is this the field you were after?
        print "Committing INSERT"
        c = db.execute("""INSERT "debit" = '%s' FROM "members" WHERE "puccode" = '%s'""" % (row['Amount'], row['PUC Code Num'],))
```

As a side note, what are you trying to achieve with the `if row['Amount'] <> '0.00' or '14.95' or '16.95':` condition? As it's written it will always be true. If you want to check if the amount is not one of 0.00 or 14.95 or 16.95, use `if row['Amount'] not in ('0.00', '14.95', '16.95'):`

PS: fieldnames[5] would have returned 'T' rather than 'Amount' as lists are 0 indexed.

Comment: I'm trying to get "Amount" and "PUC Code" (not "PUC Code Num") out of the CSV/ DAT file.

Comment: I mean you have two variables named `fieldnames`. Which of the two variables are you trying to access?

Comment: Oh! Could I use "for values in row" instead of "for fieldnames in row"? How would I define the values as the fields I was wanting, namely the "Amount" and the "PUC Code" fields?

Comment: You don't need the second `for` loop at all; the first already gives you a dictionary of the row. I have added an example to (hopefully) make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, the "Amount" field was what I was after, however, now the error message is: "NameError: name 'header' is not defined."

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part. It was supposed to be `reader`, as in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61971/discussion-between-shane-morris-and-trengot).